# Thread 1: Signal sigabrt. No idea how to solve this

Tags: ios, swift

Launching a calculator app I'm making following along Lynda's "Programming for Non-Programmers" course.  Literally launching the simulator for the first time, and I get this error message in my AppDelegate.swift code section:

*Thread 1: Signal sigabrt*

My debugger reads:
*libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)*

This is all greek to me.  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You've storyboard initial view controller set?

Comment: Please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash.

Comment: Could you also show us the full error log? Also your code and your Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a few things. In your view controller, there should be three buttons on the top. Right click on the left one and it will show you a list of IBOutlet connections. Delete any that have an alert triangle next to them. If that doesn't solve your problem, try reading a little further up in your debugger to see if it says anything that gives more detail.

Comment: Fixed it perfectly.  Thank you so much!